# Extending an ODE from one input variable to two input variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have the following parabolic-shaped, non-linear ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = kx(L-x) $$
where $L$ represents some upper limit (in my case, length, but it could also be, say, carrying capacity, whatever) and $k$ is the constant of proportionality.

This ODE has the solution
$$x(t) = \frac{LA_0 e^{kLt}}{1+A_0e^{kLt}}$$
where $x(0) = A_0$ is the initial amount.

If you graph the original ODE, it looks like an upside-down parabola. I would like to extend this situation from 2-dimensions to 3-dimensions. Thus, the 3-dimensional equation would look like an upside down paraboloid.

How do I make the new differential equation with this goal in mind?

I imagine that it would be as simple as
$$\frac{dz}{dt}= kx(L-x) + ky(L-y)$$
if we consider everything to be symmetric.

If this is indeed so, I assume that solving the equation would turn it into a PDE somehow, but I'm not really sure about this (I've not studied PDE's before).

Am I on the right track? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You say you graph the original ODE $\dot x=f(x)$, but you only graph *the right-hand side* $f(x)$ of the ODE. Of course you can graph a function $f(x,y)$, but what kind of differential equation $???=f(x,y)$ do you have in mind? Neither $\dot x$ nor $\dot y$ (or anything else) would really fit into the left-hand slot here. You can have a *system* of ODEs, though: $\dot x=f(x,y)$, $\dot y=g(x,y)$.

Comment: @Hans_Lundmark I'm not sure what you mean by "you only graph the right-hand side." Indeed, when you graph any eqn $y=f(x),$ you're really only graphing the right-hand side. I'm not seeing the difference here.

Comment: When you have a function $f$ (of one variable), you can draw its graph, which is the curve $y=f(x)$. Or you can put the function as the right-hand side of an ODE: $dx/dt=f(x)$. What I'm saying, though, is that the phrase “graphing *the ODE*” doesn't really make sense. What you can graph is the *function* $f$ which constitutes *the right-hand side* of the ODE. Or you can graph the *solutions* $x(t)$ of the ODE (which are also *functions*, of course).

Comment: @Hans_Lundmark I see. In this case, then, I'm graphing $kx(L-x)$ as the graph where I'm considering the vertical axis to be the $dx/dt$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, then you're drawing the graph $y=f(x)$ of the function $f(x)=kx(L-x)$ which is the right-hand side of the ODE $dx/dt=f(x)$. And that's a very common thing to do, since it helps one to understand the behaviour of the solutions to the ODE. But if you have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ and draw its graph $z=f(x,y)$, then it's not clear what kind of connection that graph would have to some ODE or PDE, unless you say what differential equation you have in mind: *what*, exactly, is supposed to be equal to $f(x,y)$? Just “$dz/dt$”, on its own, is not a sensible answer to that question.

Comment: @Hans_Lundmark I guess I'm not understanding why the 2D case is (mostly) clear but the 3D case isn't. The graph of the original $dx/dt=f(x)$ visually depicts the rate of change WRT the position $x.$ In this case, the rate is highest near the center and less near the edges. Why would this not be the same for $dz/dt = f(x,y)$ where the rate would be highest near the center and less near the edges? What am I missing? (Unless I'm missing whether it's an ODE or a PDE and the choice of which would affect the function and/or graph...)

Comment: But what is $z$ then? In the first case, you have the same $x$ in the left-hand side $dx/dt$ as in the right-hand side $f(x)$, but in the other equation there is a $z$ on the left and $x$ and $y$ on the right, and no explanation of how they might be connected.

Comment: @Hans_Lundmark Good point. Let's assume the 2D cases is the flow of water upwards through a cylinder. Then $x$ is the distance from the inside wall of the cylinder. So, by the $dx/dt$, water flows fastest near the center of the tube and slowest near the edge walls of the tube. Hence, the parabolic shape of the diffy-Q. Now, I want to extend this to the 3D case where the three dimensions of the cylinder are taken into account. Hence, the $z=f(x,y)$ and why I have a fluid flow rate of $dz/dt = F(x,y)$ for some function $F.$ Does that goal make sense (even if my process is incorrect)?

Comment: Oh, in that case you shouldn't have $dx/dt$ in the 2D case to begin with! The velocity of the flow *along* the cylinder is $dy/dt$, if $y$ is the coordinate along the cylinder and $(x(t),y(t))$ is the position of a fluid particle. From what you wrote in the question, it seemed clear that you understood the usual interpretation of the logistic equation where $x(t)$ is the population at time $t$ and $L$ is the carrying capacity of the environment; if so, it should be clear that the fluid flow situation that you are talking about now is something *completely* different.

Comment: Ah! I see now. So should my equation be $dy/dt = f(x(t), y(t))$ then?

Comment: That would make more sense, but to describe the situation completely you also need an equation $dx/dt=g(x(t),y(t))$ to describe how $x$ changes with time.

Comment: Well, since this is fluid flow through a cylinder, then there is no movement of water along the $x$-axis (only along the vertical $y$-axis). So $dx/dt=0.$ Of course, in reality, there would probably be *some* lateral movement along the $x$-axis, but in my simplified model there wouldn't.

Comment: OK, so in this case, there isn't much of an ODE left to solve anymore, since each fluid particle just moves in a straight line with constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x) $$

has the *input* variable $t$ and *output* variable $x$. If you want to extend this to a third variable, you'll either get

- 1 input variable, 2 output variables. This is a system of 2 equations

\begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x,y) \\ \frac{dy}{dt} &= g(x,y) \end{align}

- 2 input variables, 1 output variable. You get a *partial* differential equation instead

$$ a \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + b\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = f(u,x,y) $$

Also

> If you graph the original ODE, it looks like an upside down parabola

What you did here is graph the relationship $\frac{dx}{dt}$ vs $x$. This only works when there is no dependency on the input variable. This is different from graphing the *solution* as $x$ vs. $t$. Different variables.

A question for you is, *why*? What are you trying to accomplish by adding a third variable? It doesn't seem, to me, like you fully understand this situation.

Comment: I agree that I don't fully understand the situation. Hence, I posted my question here. In any event, I did indeed graph $\frac{dx}{dt}$ vs $x$ and *not* the solution. Based on your answer, I am probably looking at a PDE because I have two input variables (placement of x and y) and only one output variable (in my case, velocity). Thanks.